# where is <uri>model://camera</uri>?

Tags: gazebo-camera, gazebo-sensor, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am working on adding 2 camera sensors to my quad, but it uses the same link. Eventhough, I rename the joint. I am thinking of creating another camera model folder and rename the model. However, I do not know where the camera model gets reference.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15363/where-is-%3Curi%3Emodel://camera%3C/uri%3E-?/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2792/vinh-k/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think there are a few things which need to be clarified.

#### Change name inside the include tag

The uri as you put in your question is used inside the `<include>` tag. If all you want is to have two cameras with different names, you can add a `<name>` tag inside the include as follows:

```
<include>
  <name>camera_1</name>
  <pose>1 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <uri>model://camera</uri>
</include>
<include>
  <name>camera_2</name>
  <pose>2 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <uri>model://camera</uri>
</include>
```

#### model://

URIs beginning with `model://` look for models in paths indicated by the environment variable `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`.  See [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components&cat=get_started) tutorial for more information.

In case the model can't be found locally, Gazebo looks for it on the online model database. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/e6f90a80cd027faff5a74d32ae5c93511221cd22/camera/model.sdf?fileviewer=file-view-default)'s the camera model in the database. Once Gazebo downloads it the first time, it places the model under the `~/.gazebo/models/` directory so it can be found locally in the future. If you check that directory in your computer, you should find the camera there.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0